Adding component via TypeScript in Angular dynamically
I searched the internet for a solution but I can't find one, either because some functions are deprecated or do not exist. I'm trying to automatically output dynamic text inside of a component, but I can't figure it out.
The component in question is structured like this:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat-bubble',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './chat-bubble.component.html',
  styleUrl: './chat-bubble.component.scss'
})
export class ChatBubbleComponent{
  text: string = '';
  @HostBinding("class") @Input() textType: 'send' | 'receive' = 'send';
}

It's very simple. Now I want to create this chat-bubble component inside this component dynamically:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chatbot',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ContentCardComponent, ButtonComponent, InputSelectComponent, ReactiveFormsModule, ChatBubbleComponent],
  templateUrl: './chatbot.component.html',
  styleUrl: './chatbot.component.scss'
})
export class ChatbotComponent{
  options = new FormGroup({
    'style': new FormControl('short'),
    'model': new FormControl('open-ai'),
    'argument': new FormControl('delibere'),
  })

  chat = new FormGroup({
    'message': new FormControl('')
  })

  onSubmitOptions() {
    console.log(this.options.value);
  }

  onSubmitChat() {
    console.log(this.chat.value);
  }
}

"message" should be the message that will be displayed in the text property of the chat-bubble. I'm not gonna share the html for the last component because it's too long but just imagine there's a div and I want to put the chat bubbles inside that div. Thank you in advance

Why not just put <app-chat-bubble /> to the template? I don't understand the problem.

@JSONDerulo Because I have a input field, and every time I submit a text I need to create a app-chat-bubble component with the inserted text

Then you need to store the messages in an array, and loop over it in the template. I still don't see how this is problematic.

@JSONDerulo One thing I didn't say in my post is that I am a beginner, wouldn't this approach create every message in the array over again every time i send a message? Or is angular really this smart?

You can read more about this in the docs: https://angular.dev/guide/templates/control-flow#repeat-content-with-the-for-block

I tried it and it actually works thanks!

Seeing your template file is important to helping you resolve your issue.
As the comment pointed out, you need to call the app-chat-bubble component in your template file.
You will need to update the chat bubble component to mark text as an input:
@Input text: string = '';

To get the value of the message form control to the component, you would do this in your html template:
<app-chat-bubble [text]="chat.get('message')?.value" />

Since the message form control is part of the chat form group, in your template, you must get the form control from the group.

The problem is that I don't just want to replace the text, I want to create the bubble chat component again with the new text
